# Remove only formatting on a cell range selection with google spreadsheet API

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I am looking for a way to remove only formatting on a cell range selection, not their content, using Google sheet API with python.

For now, the only solution I have is to apply the same logic as a normal format and setting the style to NONE. For example, when I set a border format to a specifical range, I use:

```
    request_dict = {'requests': [{
                    "updateBorders": {
                      "range": {
                        "sheetId": sheetId,
                        "startRowIndex": 1,
                        "endRowIndex": raws,
                        "startColumnIndex": first_col,
                        "endColumnIndex": last_col},
                      "top": {
                        "style": "SOLID_MEDIUM",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}},
                      "bottom": {
                        "style": "SOLID_MEDIUM",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}},
                      "left": {
                        "style": "SOLID_MEDIUM",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}},
                      "right": {
                        "style": "SOLID_MEDIUM",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}},
                      "innerHorizontal": {
                        "style": "SOLID_MEDIUM",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}},
                      "innerVertical": {
                        "style": "SOLID_MEDIUM",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}}}}]}
body = {'requests': request_dict['requests']}
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
                                   body=body).execute()
```

And if I want to delete it, I replace the "style" field with 'NONE' just like this:

```
    request_dict = {'requests': [{
                    "updateBorders": {
                      "range": {
                        "sheetId": sheetId,
                        "startRowIndex": 1,
                        "endRowIndex": raws,
                        "startColumnIndex": first_col,
                        "endColumnIndex": last_col},
                      "top": {
                        "style": "NONE",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}},
                      "bottom": {
                        "style": "NONE",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}},
                      "left": {
                        "style": "NONE",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}},
                      "right": {
                        "style": "NONE",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}},
                      "innerHorizontal": {
                        "style": "NONE",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}},
                      "innerVertical": {
                        "style": "NONE",
                        "width": 1,
                        "color": {"blue": 0}}}}]}
body = {'requests': request_dict['requests']}
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
                                   body=body).execute()
```

But it means I need to define a function to erase format for each kind of format I define, which is not very practical...
The first step would be to find a way to erase formatting on a whole sheet, and maybe after to be able to do it for a specifical range in my sheet.

Comment: I have no clue... but may be you could copy the format from a known, unformatted cell.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same question and figured it out. The other answer is close but for anyone else who stumbles across this. In the [api samples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet) they indicate you can use [updateCells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest) to clear formatting which takes a [gridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange) argument. gridRange documentation says

> Missing indexes indicate the range is unbounded on that side.

Therefor leave off all indexes to affect the entire worksheet.

To clear an entire worksheet:

```
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateCells": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

To clear a range:

```
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateCells": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "startRowIndex": 1,
                    "endRowIndex": raws,
                    "startColumnIndex": first_col,
                    "endColumnIndex": last_col
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

Answer (score 6):

[This documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet) seems to state that if you set `fields` to `"userEnteredValue"` in an `updateCells` request that it will remove all formatting. I haven't tested this yet but here you go:

```
request_dict = {
    "requests": [{
        "updateCells": {
              "range": {
                  "sheetId": sheetId,
                  "startRowIndex": 1,
                  "endRowIndex": raws,
                  "startColumnIndex": first_col,
                  "endColumnIndex": last_col
             },
             "fields": "userEnteredValue"
         }
     }]
}
```

Comment: I had an edit that seems to indicate that `userEnteredValue` should be `userEnteredFormat` instead ... makes sense but again I haven't tested it. If someone tests it and comments here I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am using `fields: 'userEnteredFormat'` for this but with a `repeatCell` instead of an `updateCells` command

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and could be referring to v3, but I thought I would add what worked for me:

```
{
repeatCell: {
    range: {
        sheetId: sheetId,
        startRowIndex: 0,
        endRowIndex: <rows>,
        startColumnIndex: 0,
        endColumnIndex: <columns>
    },
    fields: "userEnteredFormat"
}
```