# How to set formatting with Google sheets API for python?

Tags: google-sheets-api

In theory this was answered in [Remove only formatting on a cell range selection with google spreadsheet API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801313/remove-only-formatting-on-a-cell-range-selection-with-google-spreadsheet-api) but for the life of me I cannot get it to work.

I want to write a function that clears the formatting of a given Google Sheet.  Here is what I think is the right way to do it based on the above:

```
def clear_sheet_formatting():
    spreadsheetID = "1pQoBG0q6f0Ni6yMiC9BSIXVLGMmvBRc07pGXqMA2VtA"

    global service_spreadsheets
    open_connection()

    body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "updateCells": {
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": "Sheet1",
                    },
                    "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    func = lambda: service_spreadsheets.batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetID,
                                                    body=body).execute()
    result = execute_query(func)
```

The sheet itself is very boring:
[image: Screenshot of boring google sheet]

But I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING:root:Google API call failed with the following error, sleeping 20 seconds: Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_cells.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32), "Sheet1"
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I perform a test regarding this, use this sample code to see if that helps.

I'm currently using this scopes:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets' ]
```

And the sample code I'm using is:

```
    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Sheets API and the sheet ID for "Sheet1"
        # the ID is not the name of the sheet but a number.
        call_sheet_with_format = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID).execute()
        sheets_with_format = call_sheet_with_format.get('sheets', '')
        sheet_id = sheets_with_format[0].get("properties", {}).get("sheetId", 0)

        request_body = {
            'requests': [
                {
                    'updateCells': {
                        'range': {
                            'sheetId': sheet_id
                        },
                        'fields':'userEnteredFormat'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }

        request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=request_body)
        response = request.execute()



    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)
```

Or you can get the sheetId directly in the Google Sheet:
[image]

And remove this part of the

```
        sheets_with_format = call_sheet_with_format.get('sheets', '')
        sheet_id = sheets_with_format[0].get("properties", {}).get("sheetId", 0)
```

Comment: Excellent! I have no clue what I was doing wrong but this fixed it.